I have a problem with a web-app yaml file in a minikube cluster where its supposed to be accessed via the browser
I encountered an issue with not accessing the node through the web browser. I set all settings properly i'm assuming. I'm trying to figure out what the issue is.
This is the yaml file below:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webapp-deployment
  labels: 
    app: webapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: webapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: 
        app: webapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: webapp
        image: nanajanashia/k8s-demo-app:v1.0
        resources:
          limits:
           memory: 512Mi
           cpu: "1"
          requests:
            memory: 256Mi
            cpu: "0.2"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        env:
        - name: USER_NAME
          valueFrom: 
             secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo-secret
              key: mongo-password
        - name: USER_PWD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo-secret
              key: mongo-password
        - name: DB_URL
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: mongo-config
              key: mongo-url
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webapp-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: webapp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 30100

Upon applying the yaml file:
sniper@Terrys-MBP in K8S-Demo
$ kubectl apply -f webapp.yaml
deployment.apps/webapp-deployment created
service/webapp-service created

I successfully deployed the pods:
$ kubectl get pod
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mongo-deployment-6f559676cc-ttrd7    1/1     Running   0          26m
webapp-deployment-6bdbf85f5c-mzm5q   1/1     Running   0          25m

The IP is properly set:
$ kubectl get svc
NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes       ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          37m
mongo-service    ClusterIP   10.97.254.141   <none>        27017/TCP        28m
webapp-service   NodePort    10.110.89.181   <none>        3000:30100/TCP   27m

This is the minikube ip:
$ minikube ip
192.168.49.2

When i run the IP below in the browser it doesn't load:
192.168.49.2:30100


Based on the minikube guide @ https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/, it seems that you need to run the following command using minikube CLI:
minikube service webapp-service --url

The command will create a tunnel to the service and then output the URL that you can use to access the service from your browser, for example:
http://127.0.0.1:57123


I ran the command (minikube service webapp-service --url) but this is the error I got: ❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on darwin, the terminal needs to be open to run it. https://stackoverflow.com/users/34586/lukman

@cheebi, that is not an error. It's just an instruction. Just follow the instruction.

My terminal was open when i ran it and when i put the ip in the browser I got no response ! https://stackoverflow.com/users/34586/lukman

It worked but my web page didnt show on the browser.
